# Data cleaning in R: grouping by number and then by name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

A small sample of my dataset looks something like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,1,7,1)
y <- c("A","b","a","F","A",".A.","B")
data <- cbind(x,y)
```

My goal is to first group data that have the same number together and then followed by the same name together (A,a,.A. are considered as the same name for my case).
In other words, the final output should look something like this:

```
xnew <- c(1,1,3,7,1,2,4)
ynew <- c("A","A","a",".A.","B","b","F")
datanew <- cbind(xnew,ynew)
```

Currently, I am only able to group by number in the column labelled x. I am unable to group by name yet. I would appreciate any help given.

Note: I need an automated solution as my raw dataset contains over 10,000 lines for the x and y columns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you have is a dataframe `data <- data.frame(x,y)` and not a matrix which is being generated with `cbind` you could combine different values into one using `fct_collapse` and then `arrange` the data by this new column (`z`) and `x` value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

data %>%
  mutate(z = fct_collapse(y, 
                          "A" = c('A', '.A.', 'a'), 
                          "B" = c('B', 'b'))) %>%
  arrange(z, x) %>%
  select(-z) -> result

result
#  x   y
#1 1   A
#2 1   A
#3 3   a
#4 7 .A.
#5 1   B
#6 2   b
#7 4   F
```

---

Or you can remove all the punctuations from `y` column, make them into upper or lower case and then `arrange`.

```
data %>%
  mutate(z = toupper(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", y))) %>%
  arrange(z, x) %>%
  select(-z) -> result

result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  summarise(records = n()) %>% 
  arrange(x, y)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem right - maybe `arrange(y, x)` instead of `arrange(x, y)`? Regardless, @Ronak-Shah's answer solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

According to your question it's just a matter of ordering data.

```
result <- data[order(data$x, data$y),]
```

or considering that you wan to collate A a .A.

```
result <- data[order(data$x, toupper(gsub("[^A-Za-z]","",data$y))),]
```